# IEEE floating point conversion 32 bit

Tags: decimal, ieee-754

I am first learning conversion from decimal numbers to the IEEE 32 float standard and am confused at the moment because I see several lecture slides and examples from universities who do it one way and then others who do it another way. Particularly with getting the 1's and 0's for the decimal. So, if you have a number like 1234.567

you convert 1234 to binary no problem, but then I am very confused to how to go about converting the decimal. Originally I saw that you go

```
.567 * 2 = 1.134 = 1
.134 * 2 = .268 = 0
.268 *2 = .536 = 0
```

Notice this is how many numbers are in the decimal places. But then I see other examples keep going with the decimal to some never ending point (where to stop?). If I do it the way above I get the following:

```
10011010010 for 1234
10011010010.100 
1.0011010010100 x 2 ^ (10).

127 +10 = 137. 137 in binary is 10001001.

So 32 bits of binary is

0 for sign| 10001001 for exp| 0011010010100 0000000000
```

32 bits all together. Is this correct?

Comment: Is the integer portion 1234 (as in the boxed example) or 12345 (as in the first two paragraphs)?

Comment: Wow, sorry about that the number I am trying to convert is 1234.567.

Comment: Actually I think I got it. If I can count the amount of numbers from the right of 1 when I first convert the left number to binary I know how many times I have to multiply the decimal result by 2. As In this example if I have 10 numbers to the right of 1, I need 13 to fill the 23 allotment for the mantissa!

Comment: Yes, the fullly converted number (rounding to nearest) is `0 for sign | 10001001 for exp | 0011010010 for integer mantissa | 1001000100101 for fractional mantissa`, or `0x449A5225` in hex, which is equal to `1234.5670166015625` in decimal

Answer (score 0):

Second approach is absolutely good. But, while calculating binary for 0.567, if you're not reaching to end point (i.e **0.0**) then, at least go upto 23 bit (**length of mantissa**).

For your decimal 1234.567

```
binary of 1234      =  100 1101 0010 

binary of 0.567     = .1001 0001 0010 0110 1110 100 (up to 23 bit)

binary of 1234.567  =  100 1101 0010.1001 0001 0010 0110 1110 100

                    =  1.00 1101 0010 1001 0001 0010 0110 1110 100 * 2^10
Hence,
Exponent = 10
Normalized Mantissa (with adjusted length 23 bit) =  001 1010 0101 0010 0010 0100

Sign bit = 0

Hence 32 bit floated conversion :

0 - 1000 1001 - 001 1010 0101 0010 0010 0100
```